# Duplicate answers - clean them up?

Tags: discussion, editing

[This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4979/9390) (originially from Stack Overflow) has heaps of duplicate answers. Many users suggested the exact same changes to the code, presumably while the question was not yet migrated; most of the answerers don't have accounts on Code Review.

Can we get rid of this duplication without offending the answerers? Is there an established way of fixing answers like these? How can we clean up the mess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the linked question the answers were posted almost the same time, the answerers probably wrote them parallel.

I don't know what's the policy about this on Stack Overflow but as far as I see it's common there that an easy question get some similar answers in a short period of time. I would not think that this is bad. Furthermore, I would not like to be the person who decides which answer should stay and which should go. Anyway, you can use your upvotes of course :-)

At least it helps to improve the [answer ratio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review) a little bit.